# Microsoft MediaPlayer Memory Leak winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

Hello when I play a video on a loop more and more memory is continually gobbled up. When I try to dispose of the MediaPlayer control only some of the memory is freed up.

My program needs to play hundreds / thousands of audios but this is results in my program getting larger and larger and slowing down.

Any ideas?

```
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        addTimer.Tick += addTimer_Tick;
        addTimer.Interval = 1000;
        addTimer.Start();
    }

    void addTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\temp\Catching.avi";

        if (this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia != null)
        {
            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear();
        }

        WMPLib.IWMPMedia currentMedia = this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(@"c:\temp\Catching.avi");
        this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia = currentMedia; 
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.RemoveByKey("wmp");
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: I would bet that you are stacking `currentMedia` objects on the timer tick event.  Not super familiar with this library but it would seem you need to release the file when you recall it to loop.  It looks like it would just keep opening the file but never closing it.  Also you may want to investigate using lower level media libraries than the windows media player.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.

If in addTimer_Tick I Just put in 

this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"c:\temp\Catching.avi";

And remove all the other stuff. The same thing happens. 

Thanks

Comment: Also, the method you are using to loop playback is probably not the best way to go.  You are continuously opening the file (which is where your memory leak is ocurring.  try `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop",true);` wherever you are setting the file to loop.